# Why does pgfplots plot functions only until x = 5 and y = 5?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Why does pgfplots plot functions only until x = 5 and y = 5, but not any further?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

%%%<
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}
%%%>

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[samples=100,ymin=0,ymax=10,xmin=0,xmax=20]

\addplot [thick] plot  (\x,  {1/(1 + exp(-0.6*(\x - 12)))});
\addplot plot (\x, {\x});

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Because that's the default domain. You can define over what range to plot the function by setting `domain=0:20`, for example. `xmin` and `xmax` only set the *axis* range (what you can see) but not the *calculation* range (what is computed). By the way, instead of saying `\addplot plot (\x, {\x});`, you can also say `\addplot {x};`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a lot of "domain" options in `pgfplots`.  The one which you are asking about is simply `domain`, which specifies what values of `x` (you don't need the backslash if you're using `pgfplots`) are used in plotting; by default, we have `domain = -5:5`, which is what the author apparently thinks is reasonable for typical graphs.  There is a corresponding `y domain` for two-variable functions.

This domain is quite different from the limits established by `xmin` and `xmax`.  While `domain` is set per-plot, these keys are set per-axis and just confine the actual *drawing* to these limits.  There are corresponding `ymin` and `ymax`.  These will be computed automatically by `pgfplots` if they are not given, but it is necessary for a really polished picture to set them yourself.  Note that `y domain` does *not* have anything to do with `ymin` and `ymax` in a plot of one-variable functions, because it determines the inputs of the non-existent variable `y`.  Instead, `ymin` and `ymax`, if they were determined automatically, would be calculated from the values output by your plotted functions across the `domain`.

There are more!  My favorites are `restrict x to domain` and `restrict y to domain`, which are filters with the same input syntax as `domain`.  These don't determine what numbers are used in the variables; they determine what values are used in the plot.  They are enormously helpful with parametric or uncontrollable functions; i.e. `\addplot {1/x};` will, with the default `domain = -5:5`, produce a rather hideous asymptote at `x = 0` as well as (with the default `ymin` and `ymax`) a badly distorted view of the axes.  But setting `restrict y to domain = -5:5` in this plot will simply eliminate the large values, removing the asymptote and also scaling the picture back to a proportional square.

Or, alternatively, a parametric plot such as `\addplot ({exp(x)},{exp(-x)});` (a funny way of drawing the same thing in the first quadrant alone), which is hard to tune directly because of the logarithmic connection between values on the plot and values of the variable.  For this, both the default `domain` and the default axis sizes are inappropriate; I usually leave `domain` as it is (which gives numbers that are too huge in both coordinates) and then set `restrict x to domain` and `restrict y to domain` accordingly to trim the picture nicely.  This is not to say it's a good idea to be *completely* oblivious to `domain`, since those points *are* computed...just not used.

These filter keys are different from the min and max keys because they actually ignore the filtered-out values, rather than simply cutting them out of the picture.  This is essential if these values are larger than TeX is capable of computing with.

Finally, there are `samples` or `sample at`, which latter exists mutually exclusively with `domain` and say how many, or even *exactly* at which values of `x` to compute values.  This can be an alternative to the `restrict to domain` keys, if you choose the samples carefully to avoid exceptional inputs.  They are also useful for tuning the plot around rapidly-varying places in the graph, which would otherwise look rather choppy.  These also interact with the `restrict to domain` keys in the sense that with, say,

```
\addplot[
  domain = -5:5,
  samples = 11,
  restrict x to domain = -1:1,
  restrict y to domain = -1:1
] ({exp(x)},{exp(-x)});
```

there will be exactly 11 points evaluated, namely `({exp(-5)},{exp(5)})` through `({exp(5)},{exp(-5)})`, but only those with both coordinates in the interval `[-1,1]` will be plotted.  Unfortunately, the only point with that property is `({exp(0)},{exp(0)}) = (1,1)`, so your plot will be rather vacant.  *The un-plotted points are not even used to anchor interpolating curves!*  So the filter keys are not a panacea.

My pictures tend to set *all* of these keys, since they each affect the drawing differently.

Comment: Nice overview! Two things: 1. While `sample at` and `domain` are mutually exclusive, `samples` and `domain` are not (I guess you didn't actually mean that, but that's how I read it). 2. Discarding points using `restrict x to domain` is probably okay in most situations, but it does introduce unnecessary computations. Setting the `domain` (or `samples at`) to appropriate values can sometimes be required if you have functions that are very expensive to evaluate.